# Replace text between strings SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, search, replace

I've got text between standard tags in a SQL database, which I want to remove.
The text is spread over multiple tables.

I want to remove these whole lines (including comment-tag), where the text between the comment-tags is different for every place its in.

```
<!--1234--><div style="display:none;"><a href="http://www.nu.nl/">test</a></div><!--/1234-->
```

How do I do this?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: It's my MySQL, I use PHPmyAdmin.
I can do a export, so I can do a search and replace with textmate for example. Just don't know what the search wildcard is. 

Tried searching for <!-- 1234-->.*<!--/1234-->. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use .NET , simply

```
Regex.Replace(Txt, "<(.|\\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

and then send it to sql again

***EDIT:***

since you are using **mac** then go to php

```
<?php
    $text = '';// get your string from database and then use strip_tags()
    echo strip_tags($text);
?>
```

Comment: How can I use .NET to do this? (working on a Macbook)